# How to get the scroll bar with CSS overflow on iOS

Tags: css, ipad, ios

Developing an iPad website I tried to use the CSS property `overflow: auto` to get the scrollbars if needed in a `div`, but my device is refusing to show them even if the two fingers scroll is working.

I tried with

```
overflow: auto;
```

and

```
overflow: scroll;
```

and the result is the same.

I'm only testing on an iPad (on desktop browsers works perfectly).

Any ideas?

Comment: my problem is described very well here: http://www.webmanwalking.org/library/experiments/dsp_frames_outer_document.html

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Edit** following the comment left, kindly, by [kritzikratzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347508/kritzikratzi):

> [Starting] with ios 5beta a new property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` can be added which should result in the expected behaviour.

Some, but very little, further reading:

- [Native momentum scrolling in iOS 5](http://www.johanbrook.com/writings/native-style-momentum-scrolling-to-arrive-in-ios-5/)

[image]

---

**Original answer**, left for posterity.

Unfortunately neither `overflow: auto`, or `scroll`, produces scrollbars on the iOS devices, apparently due to the screen-width that would be taken up such useful mechanisms.

Instead, as you've found, users are required to perform the two-finger swipe in order to scroll the `overflow`-ed content. The only reference, since I'm unable to find the manual for the phone itself, I could find is here: [tuaw.com: iPhone 101: Two-fingered scrolling](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/12/13/iphone-101-two-fingered-scrolling/).

The only work-around I can think of for this, is if you could possibly use some JavaScript, and maybe jQTouch, to create your own scroll-bars for `overflow` elements. Alternatively you could use [@media queries](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet) to remove the `overflow` and show the content in full, as an iPhone user this gets my vote, if only for the sheer simplicity. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" media="only screen and (max-device width:480px)" />
```

The preceding code comes from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/), from the same article linked-to above (I'm not sure why they left of the `type="text/css"`, but I assume there are reasons.

Comment: that's very useful!

So there aren't CSS-only ways to achieve this?

Comment: Sadly not, all variations of css that might apply scroll-bars to page elements are, unfortunately, *verboten*. The only options are: 1, use JavaScript to emulate (what should be a native function) or, preferably, 2, use the @media queries to create mobile-specific stylesheets that obviate the need for scrolling-elements.

Comment: starting with ios 5beta a new property -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch can be added which should result in the expected behaviour.

Comment: @kritzikratzi: thank you for the update! I hadn't heard anything of that, 'til now; interesting find :)

Comment: I found http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/ Overthrow.js to polyfill for devices that don't support overflow:scroll such as iOS4.

Comment: Very interesting solution.... unfortunately with this method scrollbar is visible only during scrolling, and not always.....

Comment: yes, i am looking for a way to show it initially for a second (using it in a scrollable "click to open menu"). tried triggering scrollTop, but doesnt work in ios. any ideas someone?

Answer (score 20):

Apply this code in your css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfeclty on Chrome's IPAD simulator. I've yet to try it on an actual IPAD but fingers crossed, thank you !

Answer (score 18):

I have done some testing and using CSS3 to redefine the scrollbars works and you get to keep your `Overflow:scroll;` or `Overflow:auto`

I ended up with something like this...

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #C3C3C3;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}
```

The only down side which I have not yet been able to figure out is how to interact with the scrollbars on iProducts but you can interact with the content to scroll it

Comment: also this scrollbar wont be on top of the content but be like in windows where it occupies its own space (pushes content to the left). or any ideas as to avoid that?

Comment: For the record, `::-webkit-scrollbar` does not work for iPhone 4/iOS 7.

Answer (score 6):

Solution given by Chris Barr [here](http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/)

```
function isTouchDevice(){
    try{
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}

function touchScroll(id){
    if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);
    }
}
```

Works fine for me. Remove event.preventDefault if you need to use some clicks...

Answer (score 2):

The [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) javascript library will fix it right up. It has a `hideScrollbar` method that you can set to `false` to prevent the scrollbar from disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you need to make sure the element has `display:block;` applied for the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` to work.

Comment: it doesnt work for me.. chorme says that -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Other 2 peoples on SO proposed possible CSS-only solution to the problem. David Thomas' solution is perfect but has the limit that scrollbar is visible only during scrolling.

In order to have scrollbars always visible, is possible to followin guidelines suggested on the following links:

- [How can I prevent scroll bars from being hidden for OS X trackpad users in WebKit/Blink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki)
- [CSS - Overflow: Scroll; - Always show vertical scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492062/css-overflow-scroll-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 2):

make sure your body and divs have not a

```
  position:fixed
```

else it would not work

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, please try:

```
.scroll-container {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #C3C3C3;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

Use this code, it work in ios/android APP webview; It delete some not portable css code;

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve **horizontal `div` scrolling** with touch on mobile, the updated CSS fix does not work (tested on Android Chrome and iOS Safari multiple versions), eg:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

I found a solution and modified it for horizontal scrolling from before the CSS trick. I've tested it on Android Chrome and iOS Safari and the listener touch events have been around a long time, so it has good support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch.

**Usage:**

```
touchHorizScroll('divIDtoScroll');
```

**Functions:**

```
function touchHorizScroll(id){
    if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            scrollStartPos=this.scrollLeft+event.touches[0].pageX;              
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            this.scrollLeft=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageX;              
        },false);
    }
}
function isTouchDevice(){
    try{
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Modified from vertical solution (pre CSS trick):

http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/