# How to force a scroll bar to appear in the ipad? (Mobile Safari)

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I am having trouble getting a scroll bar to appear in mobile safari because overflow: auto does not work when there is scroll-able content.  I found this css property:

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

as some suggested this is a fix for mobile safari hiding the scroll bars but it's not working for me.  Anyone have any suggestions on how I can force there to be a scroll bar in mobile safari to give the user a visual that they are supposed to scroll?

Comment: I believe in `iOS` the scroll bar fades into the background when not in use. I don't believe you can force those little bars to display. -`webkit-overflow-scrolling` is only to force the scroll to be there, not necessarily to show the scroll bars I believe. As, like I said, I believe the bars fade to invisible when not in use.

Comment: Even the iScroll demo: http://cubiq.org/iscroll doesn't have them show up all the time, only when in use, and iScroll is sort of a catch all for forced scrolling options. I am going to state, it can't be done.

Answer (score 13):

In your CSS include:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Customize the appearance as needed.

[Stackoverflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100209/1136132)

[Original source](http://simurai.com/blog/2011/07/26/webkit-scrollbar)

Comment: Thanks! This did work, but if you also choose to enable the inertia scrolling with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` then this will override the scrollbar appearance (and make them not appear typically)

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Answer updated. It won't work if you have `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` somewhere in your CSS. The solution is either removing all the occurrences of -`webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` or putting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;`