# Scrollbar not visible on iOS application, it appears when start scrolling. Any resolution for this?

Tags: javascript, css

Scrollbar in iOS when start sliding. Here we have a list and sublist. When we select a list we will get a corresponding list sub list. if this sub list overflows we are not able to see scrollbar it appears only when the user starts sliding on the sublist. is there any solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a scroll bar to appear in the ipad? (Mobile Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842876/how-to-force-a-scroll-bar-to-appear-in-the-ipad-mobile-safari)

Comment: Duplicate easily found using search terms “ios force scrollbar”. #makeaneffort

Answer (score 1):

Well, the question is if you really want to change this *default* behaviour. Most iOS users are used to it. 
However, this should do the job. Add it to the concerning element. It kind of "overwrites" the default behaviour.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```