# chrome macOS horizontal scrollbar stays hidden no matter what (despite overflow:scroll)

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

I am trying to show the horizontal scrollbar for my overflow by default, but in chrome + macos, it doesn't seem to be working. In Safari it works just fine.

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        content that goes brrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the css (inline via style), on the parent container:

```
display: block;
width: 100px;
overflow: scroll
```

The screenshot:

[image]

If I manually click the box and slide...the scrollbar appears, but it's not the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So scrollbars are an OS and and application level setting depending on what you're using.

On mac I think you can turn them on and off for system screens, on chrome you used to be able to turn them on and off, but when I just went looking for the setting I couldn't find it in the latest version of chrome.

Unfortunately, beyond adding `overflow: scroll` to a div you have no other control over whether or not a scroll bar appears, and even if you get it to appear for yourself, there's zero guarantee that it will appear for your users.

You can check out this video of a guy changing his own Chrome settings (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTLHxboMivM) but like I say, I just had a look in the current version and couldn't see it.

Comment: also read about macos settings > preferences > always show scrollbars but that didn't work either. Can't find the scrollbars option anymore (just like you) so it looks like google is forcing the setting now?

Comment: uh huh, new update is out and this experimental feature was removed: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22674161?hl=en

Comment: @Capagris yeah, I mean I think that a lot of apps are moving away from visible scrollbars, particularly on MacOS. But importantly for your question, it's going to be user specific, so not something that you can force

Answer (score 1):

This [solution/hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154440/css-show-horizontal-scroll-bars) seems to work for Chrome/Safari on Mac:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {    
        width: 12px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {    
        height: 12px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
        background-color: #fff; 
        border-radius: 8px; 
    }
```