# Overflow-y: Scroll not showing scrollbar in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am generating a list of organisations of the left hand side of this page: http://www.ihhub.org/member-map/

This list is generated through appending `<span>` tags that are linked to the corresponding map.

My issue is - the scroll bar does not appear in CHROME but does appear in Firefox and Safari.

Any solutions?

UPDATE:

This issue appears to be isolated to MAC OS.

SOLUTION:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: What other `overflow` rules do you have? Some browsers don't play nice when you set `overflow-x` along the `overflow-y`

Comment: It appears on your posted link. Tested on chrome 48 win7

Comment: for me it is not working in Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to [CSS - Overflow: Scroll; - Always show vertical scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492062/css-overflow-scroll-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar): OSx Lion hides scrollbars while not in use to make it seem more "slick", but at the same time the issue you addressed comes up: people sometimes cannot see whether a div has a scroll feature or not.

CSS fix:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: This is almost a great solution, problem is it adds space for the scrollbar gutter that wouldn't otherwise be there. I wish there was a way to show it without taking up extra space.

Answer (score 11):

I am seeing scroll bar well. If you are using Mac, you may want to make sure that scrollbars are always shown

[image: System preferences >> general]

Comment: Hi Timo - unfortunately the scroll bar does not appear on the list of organisations when I changed the mac settings. Furthermore - I believe - that this is an issue on Chrome for Mac and Windows.

Comment: Great Timo - looks like it is just Mac that this is not appearing on automatically. I am still seeking for this solution. I have changed overflow-y:scroll to overflow:auto and no change.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css

```
.list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: scrollbartrack-vertical;
}
```

or

```
.list::-webkit-scrollbar {
   -webkit-appearance: scrollbarthumb-vertical;
}
```

Comment: Hi Timo - many thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunately it was not what I was looking for however i did come across the solution thanks to your ::-webkit-scrollbar selector.

Comment: I have shared above @Timo and I have added to the website link too. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks. No problem :)

Comment: @Timo It's not working now and coming as Invalid property value.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 8 and Google Chrome version is 48.0.2564.97. And its working perfect. See in image highlighted area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Crome Version 48.0.2564.97 m

And it is working just fine.. 
Change it to overflow-y:auto in case if there are not enough items it will not show scroll.

[image]

Comment: I am glad to see this is working on Chrome - is this on Windows. If so the issue is still on Mac. I have changed to overflow:auto as per a few comments. Please advise.