# Overflow-y: Scroll not showing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've seen some topics like this one : [Overflow-y: Scroll not showing scrollbar in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201566/overflow-y-scroll-not-showing-scrollbar-in-chrome), I've tried the solution but it didn't work.
The scroll bar is visible only when I go down, how can I make it visible always if the content is too big ?
I'm on Mac and I can't see the vertical scroll bar

```css
#content{
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean posuere, enim eu dignissim blandit, dolor urna pellentesque mauris, vel tempus lacus mi in diam. Mauris consectetur congue ullamcorper. Pellentesque ornare ac nulla eu tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus congue gravida hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. Ut at metus arcu. Vestibulum porta dolor et nibh tempor sollicitudin. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec faucibus fringilla eros, eu sollicitudin quam vehicula eget. Sed lorem odio, sodales quis ipsum non, vehicula ornare tortor. Integer lacus ante, aliquam et molestie nec, sagittis a dolor. Ut pharetra aliquam odio, at vestibulum justo sodales et. Praesent maximus sapien odio, et luctus arcu blandit et. Sed at neque eu sem congue fringilla id vitae est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been already discussed on stackoverflow, you should need to remove the default style and use WebKit's.

Have a look the attached link.

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin)

Comment: Could've commented this

Comment: Thanks I've tried but I just had a problem while writting it on Sass, my bad there

Comment: True, I'm wonder how can I posted as answer. :)