# how to make scroll bar appear all the time?

Tags: css, html

I have created a div with scroll. But scroll bar is hiding when the mouse pointer is away from the screen. Is there any possibility to show the scrollbar is showing there regardless of my mouse is hovering or no.??
 I tried it with Mozilla Firefox and chrome.

when you begin to scroll the scroll bar is appear. After you finish it will disappear.

```css
.scroll-div{

width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.scroll-div::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  /* This is the magic bit */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-div">
test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: The scroll bar is displayed properly, not hidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Overflow: Scroll; - Always show vertical scroll bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492062/css-overflow-scroll-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.scroll-div{

width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-div">
test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: the scroll bar button is still disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Yo are using `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo element which is used to style scroll. But on using it default scrollbar of browser is not displayed which is why you are not seeing it. Further, it is only supported in webkit browsers. If you want custom scrollbars you should use a javascript library like `sly` and other. If you want default scrollbar, you can remove this part

```
.scroll-div::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  /* This is the magic bit */
  display: block;
}
```

For more info on custom scrollbar/scrollbar styling, see this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWiOD286XRAhWKOY8KHeXDBT0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fcustom-scrollbars-in-webkit%2F&usg=AFQjCNEvv-dgSdNyTjIXxzcGPuqRfDjPUw&sig2=kuD1otW9vaKhucE9coqF5Q).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the display:block style and modify the css as the following.

```
.scroll-div{

 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 overflow-x:auto;
 overflow-y:auto;
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scroll-div{
  
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:visible;

}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-div">
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>



  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>


  
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
  test<br/>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but this is not  i am looking  for you see when you start to scroll a scroll bar is appearing in the right side??. i need that bar is always shown not apprearing and disapearing

Comment: thanks, but this is not i am looking for you see when you start to scroll a scroll bar is appearing in the right side??. i need that bar is always shown not apprearing and disapearin

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--please use only this very code-->

.scroll-div{

  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  }

<!--don't use this one-->

.scroll-div::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  /* This is the magic bit */
  display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code.

**CSS Code**

```
.scroll-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* This is the magic bit */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it was the issue in system preferences thank you