# when the page extends the scroll does not appear

Tags: html, css

The problem is when the page extend the scroll does not appear

I have a problem with this code

```html
<div class="yui3-lightbox act-auth-lightbox">
  <div class="yui3-lightbox-content" style="max-width: 448px;">
    <a class="zsg-icon-x-thin lightbox-close" title="Close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    <div class="lightbox-body zsg-tooltip-viewport">
      <div class="tooltip-dest">
        <div id="strength-tooltip"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="user-account login">
        <div class="module-wrap">
          <div class="module-head">
            <h2>مرحبا بكم في فرص</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="module-body">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="yui3-lightbox-mask act-auth-lightbox" style="display: block;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As in the following:

[Screenshot 1](https://1.top4top.net/p_1343yge3g1.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://2.top4top.net/p_134353aae2.png)

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll`?

Comment: this is same modal not work overflow

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Overflow: Scroll; - Always show vertical scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492062/css-overflow-scroll-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the lightbox is setting itself up to occupy the entire view using `position: fixed` (or something similar), and setting `overflow: hidden` to clip anything that doesn't fit. Assuming that's the case, your document is not exceeding the bounds of the window, hence no scrollbar.