# how to make the scroll visible

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a certain table that the amount of rows can be increased with time.
I want the scroll to be displayed immediately when the hight of the table reaches the max (150px) and not only when Im rolling my mouse (if it make sense) so the user will have an indication that there are more rows.

I tried the next style with no luck

```
  <div   id="eventType"  style="max-height:150px;overflow:scroll !important;">
```

the scroll is displayed when the table has reached the max but only when Im rolling the mouse and not immediately.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

[CSS - Overflow: Scroll; - Always show vertical scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492062/css-overflow-scroll-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar)

adding to your css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```