# Horizontal scrollbar not showing on IPhone (Tailwind)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

For some reason the horizontal scrollbar for my code block is not showing on IPhone. Here's what the code looks like (I'm using Tailwind):

```
 <div className="mx-auto mt-6 mb-6 max-w-2xl overflow-x-scroll rounded-sm bg-gray-200 px-4 py-4 md:overflow-x-auto">
```

The scroll bar shows up when I tap on the section, but i'd like it to always be visible by default (so that users know that they need to scroll horizontally to see the full text).

Any advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The reason and solution has been explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100209/10927163)