# How do I check if the page is scrollable when the user first accesses it in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar

I want to display scrollbar when the user first accesses each page

So I tried the code below:

```
function App() {
  const app = document.querySelector("#root");
  const [scrollHeight, setScrollHeight] = useState(app?.scrollHeight);

  useEffect(() => {
    setScrollHeight(app.scrollHeight);
  }, [scrollHeight])

  if (scrollHeight > window.innerHeight) {
    /* show scrollbar and do something */
  }

  return (/* some components */);
}
```

Isn't there a better idea?

Comment: You want to show scrollbar only if the page is scrollable right? If that's the case you can achieve it using css

Comment: @arp how cna i do that?

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492062/css-overflow-scroll-always-show-vertical-scroll-bar

Answer (score 2):

In page.css or wrapper html element of Page component, you can set.

For page.css:

> { overflow: auto }

For wrapper html element:

"<div style={{overflow: 'auto'}}>"

Document link: [overflow css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_overflow)