# Make scrollbars visible by default on browsers on MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, scrollbar, overflow

I just realized by default the scrollbars are hidden on MacOS browsers, and only visible while scrolling. This creates a problem in some parts of the website where without seeing the scrollbar it's hard to notice that there is scrollable content.

I looked around the internet, but couldn't find any fix that also takes into account that scrollbar customization is not supported by newer versions of iOS.

Simple example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        The content
    </div
</div
```

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #fffaaa;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7492062/1271826?

Comment: @Rob yes, but it's kind of outdated and the answer suggest using scrollbar pseudo selectors to customize the scrollbar, which is no longer supported by latest versions of iOS.

Comment: Agreed. But i thought the [“no longer supported”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68202589/1271826) answer, as unsatisfying as that undoubtedly is, was relevant. Sorry and good luck.