# CSS - no scrollbars in ipad

Tags: css

I have a stylesheet and use overflow:scroll; in my css to blend in scrollbars. It works in Firefox but not on my iPad in the safari browser. There, no scrollbars are shown but it is possible to scroll with two fingers.

Now, is that normal that iPad doesn't show  scrollbars? That would be stupid somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845445/how-to-get-the-scroll-bar-with-css-overflow-on-ios

Comment: The iPad (iOS) does not show scroll bars until you scroll, it is part of their design.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I tried it with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and I also scrolled with two fingers, but it still doesn't show scrollbars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe that is normal behaviour from iOS3 and upwards.

You might want to check it on android, as android does not support overflow:scroll at all, from what I am aware (no two fingers, no scroll bar, no way to view content beyond the fold)

[More information on iphone/ipad scrolling](http://blog.bahrenburgs.com/2009/11/div-overflow-and-iphone-browsing.html)

Answer (score 11):

You might want to turn it on with: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`