# How to show vertical scrollbar in i-os devices for textarea?

Tags: html, scroll, textarea

The vertical scroll bar in textarea is displaying in I.E,FF and Chrome but not in i-os devices like ipod/ipad.

```
<textarea  id="termsConditions" cols="30" rows="5" readonly="readonly">Sample text sample           text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample</textarea>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: see this answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845445/how-to-get-the-scroll-bar-with-css-overflow-on-ios>

Does that help you?

Answer (score 6):

Just as Michael Halpin has said. Add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` into your styles.

**HTML**

```
<textarea  id="termsConditions" cols="30" rows="5" readonly="readonly">Sample text sample           text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample</textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
#termsConditions {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4SnyJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

it Is worked for me

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 10px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); border-radius: 10px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {border-radius: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: this only work in Windows but not working in iOS as original question