# How to get a scroll on iPad?

Tags: html, css

I know, this question has been asked millions of times, but still can't get it right. I've tried everything been said on Internet, nothing!

```css
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 overflow:auto;
```

Should parents of this be `overflow: auto?` if their overflow is `hidden`, or `no-content?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the scroll bar with CSS overflow on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845445/how-to-get-the-scroll-bar-with-css-overflow-on-ios)

Comment: yeah, I saw that post, but that's not working for me!