# Apply a custom scrollbar to a div

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Im trying to apply a custom scrollbar to a `div` called `table-container`. I've tried the following CSS:

```
.table-container {
overflow: scroll;
}

.table-container::webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}

.table-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This does not work. If I take `::webkit-scrollbar` out of the `.table-container` class it works but applies it to all elements with scroll enabled. I want the above code to only apply to the `.table-container` div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Priak, you try to achieve something like this ? http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/tableDiv.html

Comment: @technico yes i have used that and it works great but since iOS devices default scrollbar is not obvious to the eye I've had to resort to a custom one but just can't get it to work on the div :(

Comment: This seems to be an harder problem ... here are some (uneasy) ways to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845445/how-to-get-the-scroll-bar-with-css-overflow-on-ios

Comment: @technico thanks for the link, i'll check it out and see if I can find any solution :)