# Show scrollbars on iOS when scrolling via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

I would like the vertical scrollbar to be displayed when I call `element.scrollTop = <somePosition>;`

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve: https://plnkr.co/edit/0ls05cCa3XrvrWPO?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

If that example is loaded on iOS, when the left box is scrolled, the right box should sync with it. That works just fine, but I need a way for the scrollbar to also show up.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845651/14457833) helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that division being scrolled via Javascript is not recognized as `active`, to keep scrollbar visible.
I would suggest to try any `custom Scrollbar` library, they manage scrollbars with divisions rather than browser's.

Many such would allow you to configure scrollbar to be shown and hidden using Javascript.

It would add additional work for you, but it can be a solution to go with.

Here are few you can try with: https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Custom-Scroll-Bar-jQuery-Plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically add a css class to the container when performing `scrollTop()`.

Try a class that implements [`overflow-y: scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) when applied. That should yield the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately `overflow: auto` and `overflow: scroll` behave the same way on iOS / iPadOS. I tried but it didn't work.
Maybe there is no solution for this.

Comment: Hello @GuilhermeLopes `overflow: auto` shows scrollbar when it's necessary & `overflow: scroll` always shows scrollbar

Comment: @AnkitTiwari not on `iOS`.